# Memory leak in Prism on detaching view from region

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks, prism

In my WPF/Prism application, a Window with a Region is repeatedly shown/closed, where the View attached to the Region is a singleton.

[image]

This repeating show/close operations cause memory leak of the Window instances (never collected until OutOfMemoryException).  So I checked the VS Profiler and found that Prism's `BindRegionContextToDependencyObjectBehavior` seems to be the root cause of the leak, as it holds an event link from RegionContext (which is not used in my app) to Region (namely, `ViewRegionContext_OnPropertyChangedEvent`).  I think Prism adds/removes this event asymmetrically when Region.Context == null, but cannot straighten this as it is private.

This does not happen if I create new View each time, but for some reason I want to reuse the instance (but not for the Window instance).

How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: Which version of Prism are you using?

Comment: I am using Prism 6.2.